# MIDI and Android: can you achieve individual "note bending" only by assigning a separate channel to every note being played?

Tags: midi, javax.sound.midi

I'm in the process of devising my idea for some music-related Android app.

It will probably feature playback using the internal MIDI sound bank (I thought of using free soundfonts but then I'm not sure how easy it is to achieve any pitch shifting at all as it's sample-based rather than synthesized), and the issue is that I want to assure it would play correctly in situations when one note slides to another without the rest shifting as well.

To my understanding the MIDI messages controlling pitch shifting are the portamento CC. Now, it's defined that MIDI supports up to 16 channels, and it's usually a channel per instrument. Could a possible solution during multitrack playback be to have every instrument within a piece play in a separate MIDI player instance and then map at any moment every note generated within that instrument to a different channel of the available 16?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In MIDI 1.0, the only way to have per-note pitch bend is to put the note, whose pitch you want to bend, in its own channel. This is called MPE in the official MIDI 1.0 spec.

Comment: So it's as I've suspected. I've seen apps where a pitch bend was possible for a note without another one bending, but if you tried to add an additional bend of a different value then all notes with a bending effect played the same. Are concurrent notes with portamento off possible on the same channel at least or was the implementation in this case probably "one additional channel for all notes that currently have portamento"? Regarding MPE, I just read about it on their website but I think you meant MIDI 2.0. Is it possibly already implemented for Android?

Comment: MIDI 2.0 has per-note pitch bend built in, it has no need for MPE, which is an extension of the MIDI 1.0 spec to allow for per-note pitch bend. Currently, no operating systems support MIDI 2.0, however if the Android 13 development timeline is to be believed, Android will support MIDI 2.0 before the end of 2022.

Comment: Perhaps that's the case, but the article about it in the MIDI website used the tag "MIDI 2.0". Anyway is that translated into existing MIDI form within Android? Or do you need to manually create code that gives a different channel to every note sent to the MIDI player (in which case I don't understand whether "MPE" actually does anything)? Also, every MIDI 1.0 instance is still limited to 16 channels, right?

Comment: Every note message you send from your code already includes the channel, so you are already doing what you call "manually create code that gives a different channel to every note". The concept of using one note per channel so that you can affect that one note with other channel messages, like portamento, is exactly what MPE does. Read the MPE specification and it will become clear to you. Yes, MIDI 1.0 has 16 channels per port. MIDI 2.0 has 256 channels per port.